# Raising Http404 in Django

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

I have the following path:

```py
path("polls/<int:week_id>/vote/", views.vote, name="vote")
```

And in my view, I wrote the following method:

```py
def vote(request, week_id):
  week = Week.objects.get(pk=week_id)
  try:
    selected_choice = week.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST["choice"])
  except Week.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404("Poll for said week does not exists")
  else:
    selected_choice.votes += 1
    selected_choice.save()
    return redirect("results", week_id)
```

I'm trying to raise an `404` page if a user navigates to `polls/123/vote`, where `123` is a non-existing week in the database. For some reason the code above returns a `DoesNotExist` error instead of the actual `404` page. I'm assuming that line of code were i'm raising the `404` page is not being hit. Is that right?

Comment: You have two calls to `.get` the first one of which is not in the try-except block `week = Week.objects.get(pk=week_id)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `week` down into the try block:

```py
def vote(request, week_id):
  try:
    week = Week.objects.get(pk=week_id)
    selected_choice = week.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST["choice"])
  except Week.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404("Poll for said week does not exists")
  else:
    selected_choice.votes += 1
    selected_choice.save()
    return redirect("results", week_id)
```

Comment: NP. Have fun with Django! It rocks.